Details on how to connect to Firebird database
I'm dealing with a Firebird database I inherited and have no documentation for. I need to connect to the database, look at the data, and see what it's being used for. At this point I have no direct operating system access and only Firebird access over port 3050. So I have the IP address, port, username, and password. I do not have the database name. I would like to start with just making sure the username and password work.
I've been trying to figure out how to use isql or FlameRobin to do this but have found it surprisingly complicated and confusing, despite looking for answers from Google and ChatGPT. Can someone give me clear instructions on how to use a tool to simply connect and dump the main database or something?
EDIT:
I was able to use isql-fb to get a bit further. The commands I used to dump the sample database are below, but I still need to figure out what the real database name is:
isql-fb "192.168.1.100:C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_0\examples\empbuild\employee.fdb" -user 'SYSDBA' -password '<password>'

select * from employee;

quit;

How do I list all the databases?

There is no "database name" in Firebird in a traditional sense, and there is no generic way to "list all the databases". Each database is stored in a dedicated file. A full file path is a database name.
Either you'll be given a full path to the database file on the DB server (as we see in the question), or that path could assigned a "alias" in the aliases.conf file, and then you use that alias to access the database instead of the full path.
There is an important security option DatabaseAccess (in the firebird.conf) which regulates access to the database files.
If it's set to None, remote users will be only allowed access to databases aliased via that file, in that case you may just list the contents of the file to get the list of accessible databases. When I was administering Firebird servers, I always set it that way.
If that option is Restrict, any aliased database and any file in the certain directory can be accessed. You can infer the list of available databases from the list of all aliases and list of files in that directory. This is the default setting, AFAIK.
If the option is Full, database files may reside anywhere on the server. Not recommended.
In any case, access to the server filesystem is required to or view files on it, so without an access you can't list anything.
Also, working as SYSDBA is, obviously, not recommended too.
